# empty() does not work when passing data from an object. Why?

Tags: php

I just discovered that `empty()` does not work when passing data from an object. Why is that?

This is my code:

```
// This works
$description = $store->description;
if (!empty($description) )
  echo $description;

//This is not working
if (!empty($store->description) )
  echo $store->description;
```

**UPDATE**
Added extra code for context.

```
// At the top of my PHP file I have this code
$store = Factory::new_store_obj($id);

// To controll that I got content, I can test by printing object
echo '<pre>';
print_r($store);
echo '</pre>';

//output
Store Object
(
    [data:Store:private] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lacrosse
            [street1] => Bygdøy Allé 54
            [street2] => 
            [zipcode] => 0265
            [city] => Oslo
            [country] => Norway
            [phone] => 22441100
            [fax] => 
            [email] => 
            [opening_hours] => 
            [keywords] => 
            [description] => Lacrosse er en bla bla bla...
        )
)
```

Comment: It works. I tried it my self. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: What is the content of `$item->description`? Is it different when you assign it to `$description`?

Comment: Could you post additional context?  Namely, how is `$item` created, what type is `$description`, what version of PHP are you using, and is it a syntax error when it's "not working"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the docs for [`empty()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). There is an explanation of why empty might fail in the comments.

For example you will get this error if `description` is a private property, you have set up a magic `__get` function without the magic `__isset` function.

So this will fail:

```
class MyClass {
    private $foo = 'foo';
    public function __get($var) { return $this->$var; }
}

$inst = new MyClass;
if(empty($inst->foo))
{
    print "empty";
}
else
{
    print "full";
}
```

and this will succeed:

```
class MyClass {
    private $foo = 'foo';
    public function __get($var) { return $this->$var; }
    public function __isset($var) { return isset($this->$var); }
}

$inst = new MyClass;
if(empty($inst->foo))
{
    print "empty";
}
else
{
    print "full";
}
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Stupid mistake by me. The data **is** private and that's why I had created `$store->getStoreData();` function.

Answer (score 1):

input:

```
<?php
$item->description = "testme";
$description = $item->description;
if (!empty($description) )
  echo $description;

//This is not working
if (!empty($item->description) )
  echo $item->description;

?>
```

output

```
testmetestme
```

**conclusion: it works**

Comment: I can `echo $item->description` and I get the output. And I can assign it to another variable. Got any ideas why it's not working here?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
class test {
    private $var = '';
    public function doit() {
        echo (empty($this->var)) ? 'empty' : 'not';
        echo '<br>';
        var_dump($this->var);
    }
}

$t = new test;
$t->doit();
```

It outputs: `empty, string(0) ""`. This means that it works. Try it your self if you want. It must be the class context not working.